# textView lines -- advice

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [textView lines - advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443220/textview-lines-advice)

row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fullnameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/wayimageView"
            android:textColor="@color/list_text_color"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
             />
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

I want set name to right of imageView. It's fine but there is one problem. When the name is too long it's going under the second imageview. I want to create seconde line if orientation is portrait but when orientation is landscape it also should appears with single line.I can't find any solution here. is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: my dear No need to create brand new question for the same problem you have already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443220/textview-lines-advice , **`instead wait for some time to have answers`** or update the existing question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically define 2 layout for your layout. one for portrait and one for landscape.

You could put landscape layout xml files in “res\layout-land” and portrait in “res\layout”.

Comment: In my adapter I use row.xml to fill listView.

Comment: then place the make a copy of row.xml and place it in res/layout-land and make the change (2 lines etc) and try your luck.

Comment: If i use this way everytime when change orientation the listView should load data. it is not a good option. but anyway thanks for your advice